# Probability of one normdist being greater than another

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have two independant normally distributed random variables.

```
X ~ N(657, 3)
Y ~ N(661, 2)

P(x > y) = ?
```

How do I calculate the probability of X being greater than Y? Using R for simulating, I am getting values around 0.13. How to get the exact ("theoretical") value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $W=X-Y$. Then $W$ has normal distribution, with easily computed mean and variance. Note that in general if $U$ and $V$ are independent, then
$$\text{Var}(aU+bV)=a^2\text{Var}(U)+b^2\text{Var}(V).$$

**Remark:** If you mean, as in the more standard convention, that the **variances** are $2$ and $3$, then the simulation was pretty good, the correct answer is close to $0.125$.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables), 
$$ X-Y \sim N(-4,\sqrt{13})$$

and you want the probability of $X-Y>0$, that is, the standard normal being $> \frac{4}{\sqrt{13}}$ which comes out to around $0.13363$ from [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%28erfc%28%20-4/sqrt%2826%29%29/2%29).

**Edit:** I'm assuming the second parameter is standard deviation, and not variance.